# Mic not working on Xbox one second profile?

Tags: xbox-one

Me and my sister share an Xbox, therefore we have two accounts and two controllers linked to each account. We recently got some headsets with mics so we can communicate with friends. My controller is the main one that came with the Xbox. I plugged my headset in and in a party it would seem to work fine. My sister plugged hers into her controller, but nothing happened. It wouldn’t show that she even had a mic plugged in. Can anybody help with this? If you need more info about this problem let me know! Thanks for helping if possible!!

Comment: Have you tried swapping the headsets/controllers? See if it's an issue with the specific headset or the specific controller or if it's a player 2 issue.

Comment: Virus, I’m not sure exactly what you mean? We both have seprate headsets but I have tried both headsets on the first controller and they both work but none of the headsets work on the second controller. Sorry if I made it confusing I just don’t know what to do.

Comment: I'm just saying to help us narrow down what exactly is causing the issue. What you've done is a good start, that means that it's not the headset. It could be the connection on the controller, **try to sign in with her controller on your account and see if your headset works**. Or it could be an issue with her account, meaning that no combination of controller/headset would work, and it's some issue with her account settings.

Comment: Thanks for replying again, for some reason (even on the first controller) the headsets have stopped completely even showing that they are connected to to the Xbox? I will try your idea but I might have to return them if they don’t work. (I have never had any sort of headset before so I know nothing about them sorry!)